# 400 Bad request while making API Call ( creating BigCommerce Order Shipment)

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc, bigcommerce

I am creating shipment for Test Order Number via API - 1745
[API_URL](https://www.lipbalm.land/api/v2/orders/1745/shipments)

JSON Data POST:

`{"tracking_number":"EJ958083578US","comments":"avb","order_address_id": 1571,"items":[{"order_product_id": 361,"quantity":1}]}`

Above post request is giving me back 400 bad request.

Can you please tell what is wrong in it?

Can you please also confirm what is `"Order_Address_ID"`. I am sending it as AdressID.

Thanks in Advance for your time and help.

Comment: Put your call code, only Json and Some explain will not work out here friend... Put the code you tried

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I sent it as json data. Here is what I did to make it work. Code is c# and for adding a product object.

In regards to order_address_id, here is the description from bigcommerce sie
"ID of the order address the shipment is associated with"

```
var createData = new
            {
                name = "Test Product,
                type = "physical",
                description = "test",
                price = "25.99",
                availability = "available",
                is_visible = true,
                weight = "3"    
            };

 string url = String.Format("products");
            var response = HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, createData);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
            Console.ReadLine();
```